# Bash/ZSH preserve quotes

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there a way to tell bash/zsh to not parse the quotes at all but give them to a shell function verbatim?

```
$ argtest abc def "ghi jkl" $'mno\tpqr' $'stu\nvwx'
abc
def
"ghi jkl"
$'mno\tpqr'
$'stu\nvwx'
```

You might be thinking why I don't just do

```
argtest abc def '"ghi jkl"' "$'mno\tpqr'" "$'stu\nvwx'"
```

But the `argtest` function I'm trying to create tries to wrap around other commands which can have `noglob` prefixes. So I need a way of being able to tell apart `*` and `'*'` .

Comment: XY problem. Tell us you how you want `argtest` to work, and we can suggest how (if at all) to best accomplish that.

Comment: @chepner "I'm trying to create a function to wrap around other commands which can have noglob prefixes."

Comment: What I mean is, what kind of wrapping are you trying to do? Can you give an example of how `noglob` fits with this?

Comment: "bash/zsh" is a messy turn of phrase -- when you get into implementation-specific details, they're **very** different shells, and you're unlikely to get answers that apply to both of them here.

Comment: By the way -- in contexts where the difference between `*` and `'*'` matters, the usual approach is to check whether the file exists. If it exists, treat it as a glob expansion; if it doesn't, report a failure on the presumption that it was a bad glob that didn't expand. Alternately, require your callers to use `shopt -s nullglob` and disable literal passing of unexpanded globs altogether.

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh`, you can use the `q` parameter expansion flag, but it's messy. One `q` escapes individual characters as necessary; two expands the text in single quotes; three in double quotes. (The notation `${:-stuff}` simply expands to the text following `:-`; it's a wrapper that allows you to create anonymous parameters.)

```
$ echo "foo bar"
foo bar
$ echo ${(qq):-"foo bar"}
'foo bar'
$ echo ${(qqq):-"foo bar"}
"foo bar"

$ argtest () {
function>   echo "$1"
function> }
$ argtest "foo bar"
foo bar
$ argtest ${(qqq):-"foo bar"}
"foo bar"
```

Comment: interesting one. not the most readable but interesting. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to disable the shell's quote handling.

If you want this for your own convenience, reading arguments from a here document or similar might be acceptable.

But if you want your users to be able to write quotes at the shell prompt and have them preserved, there is no way to do that (short of writing your own shell).

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can access `$BASH_COMMAND` to see the literal, pre-parsing command being executed. Thus, while you can't prevent the shell from parsing an argument list, you *can* see its pre-parsed state.

However -- this gives you only the entire argument; you need to do string-splitting yourself, if going this route. As such, I would describe this as an ill-advised course of action.

Comment: This works for my purposes, is there a zsh equivalent?

Comment: Damned if I know. Frankly, I'd suggest splitting this into two separate questions -- one for bash, one for zsh. Otherwise, it's like "C++/ObjC" -- a person expert in one isn't particularly likely to be similarly familiar with the other.